# Bash "ps" parallel processes and check when they're done

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Having a large set of files I need to grep through, I'm doing it within a bash script like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

REX="word"
grep -IP $REX A* >> result &
grep -IP $REX B* >> result &
grep -IP $REX C* >> result &
grep -IP $REX D* >> result &
[..]
```

How to know when all the processes are finished?

Comment: Why not use `find` and `xargs` to find all the files you need and process them in parallel?

Comment: or GNU or BSD `parallel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go about solving your problem a different way. `find` can find specific files on your filesystem, and `xargs` allows you to run commands on given input files. So I would use a command like this:

```
find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} -n1 -P4 grep -IP $REX '{}' >> result
```

This would search, starting in the current directory (`./`) for all regular files (`-type f`), and pass them along to `xargs` safely in case there are any spaces in the filename (`-print0`). `xargs` then, for each command, runs your `grep` command. `-I{}` tells `xargs` that where it sees `{}` it will insert the filename into the command. Not strictly necessary here, but good practice. `-0` goes hand in hand with `-print0` from `find`, and tells it to expect input that way. `-P4` tells `xargs` to run up to 4 processes at the same time, and `-n1`, as described by the man page, hints to `xargs` to only use one argument at a time per command.

There are various tweaks you can make here, whether it's not wanting to search for all files, or to only go to a certian depth, but this general command should get you started with this kind of task.

Comment: The parallel execution of grep might lead to mingled output in the result file, and is thus a suboptimal idea. Once -P4 is out of the way, you can simply use `find . -type f -exec grep -IPh $REX "{}" "+" >>result` without the need for xargsing. (I gather that using xargs with `-n1` will lead to no filename being print in front by grep, henceforth compensated by the `-h` grep option.)

Answer (score 4):

Use the bash built-in 'wait'

> wait [n ...]
>
> Wait for each specified process and return its termination status. Each n may be a process ID or a job specification; if a job spec is given, all processes in that job's pipeline are waited for. If n is not given, all currently active child processes are waited for, and the return status is zero. If n specifies a non-existent process or job, the return status is 127. Otherwise, the return status is the exit status of the last process or job waited for.

In your case it should be enough to just:

```
REX="word"
grep -IP $REX A* >> result &
grep -IP $REX B* >> result &
grep -IP $REX C* >> result &
grep -IP $REX D* >> result &

echo "Waiting..."
wait
echo "All child terminated"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking that the output of `jobs -p | wc -l` is zero lines long.

FYI: there are better ways to do parallel processing than using the shell as a job manager. `find -print0` to `xargs -0 -P` is my personal favorite.

Comment: @pistacchio `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "[ABCD]*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -IP $REX >> result`

Answer (score 0):

use wait.  I don't even think you need to save and specify pids in this case e.g.

```
    #! /usr/bin/env bash

REX="word"
grep -IP $REX A* >> result &
grep -IP $REX B* >> result &
grep -IP $REX C* >> result &
grep -IP $REX D* >> result &
[..]
wait
echo "done"
```

Note that there are way better ways to do this than listing everything out.  You can pipe ls into xargs, or use exec with find, for instance.